# Convert ALL UPPERCASE to Title

Tags: python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

import urllib.request
import os
import re

os.chdir('/home/whatever/')
a = open('Shopstxt.csv','r')
b = a.readlines()
a.close()
c = len(b)
d = list(zip(*(e.split(';') for e in b)))

shopname = []
shopaddress = []
shopcity = []
shopphone = []
shopwebsite = []
f = d[0]
g = d[1]
h = d[2]
i = d[3]
j = d[4]
e = -1

for n in range(0, 5):
    e = e + 1
    sn = f[n]
    sn.title()
    print(sn)
    shopname.append(sn)
    sa = g[n]
    sa.title()
    shopaddress.append(sa)
    sc = h[n]
    sc.title()
    shopcity.append(sc)
```

Shopstxt.csv is all upper case letters and I want to convert them to title.  I thought this would do it but it doesn't...it still leaves them all upper case.  What am I doing wrong?

I also want to save the file back.  Just wanting to check on a couple of things real quick like as well...time pressed.

When I combine the file back together, before writing it back to the drive do I have to add an '\n' at the end of each line or does it automatically include the '\n' when I write each line to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, so you need to asign the result of `title()`:

```
sa = sa.title()
sc = sc.title()
```

Also, if you do this:

```
with open("bla.txt", "wt") as outfile:
    outfile.write("stuff")
    outfile.write("more stuff")
```

then this will *not* automatically add line endings.

A quick way to add line endings would be this:

```
textblobb = "\n".join(list_of_text_lines)
with open("bla.txt", "wt") as outfile:
    outfile.write(textblobb)
```

As long as `textblobb` isn't inefficiently large and fits into memory, that should do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.title()` method when defining your variables like I did in the code below. As others have mentioned, strings are immutable so save yourself a step and create the string you need in one line.

```
for n in range(0, 5):
    e = e + 1
    sn = f[n].title()  ### Grab and modify the list index before assigning to your variable
    print(sn)
    shopname.append(sn)
    sa = g[n].title()  ###
    shopaddress.append(sa)
    sc = h[n].title()  ###
    shopcity.append(sc)
```